# Элемент из css в js

Tags: css, javascript

Есть такая штука:

```
 ul.menu li a, ul.menu li span {
       ...........
         }
```

Мне нужно взять этот элемент в js, попробовал так:

```
    "document.getElementById('ul.menu li a').style.display ='none';" +
    "document.getElementById('ul.menu li span').style.display ='none';})()");
```

Не помогает, затем поробовал так:

```
"document.getElementsByTagName('ul').getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li').getElementsByTagName('a').style.display ='none';" +
    "document.getElementsByTagName('ul').getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li').getElementsByTagName('span').style.display ='none';})()");
```

Тоже никак. Так как мне взять этот элемент из css?

Comment: * [querySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)
* [querySelectorAll](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Comment: document.querySelector('.ul.menu li span').style.display ='none';

Если так делать, тоже ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById('menu') будет искать элемент с id="menu".
У тебя же есть только <ul class="menu"> Работать естественно не будет, т.к. требуемого элемента не находит.

Comment: А как мне вызвать этот элемент?

Comment: 1 вариант - добавить элементу id и использовать getElementById.  
2 вариант - использовав querySelectorAll, получить массив элементов определенного класса и по номеру указать нужный.  
3 вариант - использовать jquery для удобства. Строку типа "ul.menu li a" библиотека легко поймет. Но таких строк может быть много, поэтому надо будет также указать порядковый номер в найденном массиве.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало как часы

        "$(document).ready(function() {"+
        " $('ul.menu').css('width', '100%');" +
        " $('ul.menu > li> a').css('padding-bottom', '0px');" +
        "$('ul.menu > li> span').css('float', 'left')});" +
        "})()");

Answer (score 0):

Вы писали:

> document.querySelector('.ul.menu li
> span').style.display ='none';
>
> если так делать, тоже ничего не
> происходит

Попробуйте спану присвоить класс. И уберите точку у ul, это же тег у вас, а не класс.

Comment: У меня нет доступа к сайту.

Comment: Хорошо, но точку перед ul в селекторе вы убрать можете?

Comment: да, конечно, я попробывал, и всё равно ничего не происходит

Comment: Тогда, что то с селектором у вас потому, как работать должно. Или с браузером.